# Why " throw" will display a warning?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostringstream;

class illegalParameterValue {

private:
    string message;
public:
    illegalParameterValue() : message("Illegal parameter value") {}
    explicit illegalParameterValue(const char* theMessage) {message = theMessage;}
    void outputMessage() {cout << message << endl;}

};

int main() {

    ostringstream s;
    s << "index = " << 1 << " size = " << 2;
    throw illegalParameterValue(s.str().c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

I just use some code like this, but the `throw` will remind some warnings which called

> Clang-Tidy: Throwing an exception whose type 'illegalParameterValue' is not derived from 'std::exception'

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Make your exception derive (inherit) from `std::exception`?

Comment: by deriving from std::exception?

Comment: The message is literally telling you what to do. What is confusing you?

Comment: If I do not derive from std::exception, will it go wrong ? @Mad Physicist

Comment: Give it a shot and see what happens

Comment: If I don’t derive from the exception, I haven’t found any problems, but I’m afraid there will be hidden problems, so I want to know why it is.@Mad Physicist

Comment: There is nothing wrong by throwing something else than a `std::exception`. If you have some reason to throw another type, just ignore this warning.

Comment: You have to decide who is in control of your program design, you or the compiler. The code is legal and its meaning is well defined. The compiler is giving you style advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the following code:

```
try {
  // do something that might throw an exception
}
catch (const std::exception &ex) {
  // handle the exception
}
```

If you derive your `illegalParameterValue` class from `std::exception`, then the catch clause above will catch it (along with other kinds of exceptions derived from `std::exception`). As currently written, it will not. Your users will have to add another catch clause:

```
try {
  // do something that might throw an exception
}
catch (const std::exception &ex) {
  // handle std exceptions
}
catch (const illegalParameterValue &ip) {
  // handle illegal parameter exeception
}
```

Maybe that's what you want, maybe not.
But there's a lot of code out there like the first case.